# не меняется disabled в input

Tags: javascript

Есть небольшая форма, которая спрашивает, работаешь ли ты. Если это так, то тогда становятся доступны остальные поля для заполнения:

```
<form class="last">
            <div class="form_line">
                <p class="text">Вы трудоустроены?</p>
                <div class="check">
                    <input id="job" type="checkbox" name="job" value="job" checked="false" onclick="job()">
                    <label for="job"></label>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form_line">
                <p class="text">Город, адрес работы</p>
                <input id="job_1" type="text" disabled="true">
            </div>
            <div class="form_line">
                <p class="text">Название организации</p>
                <input id="job_2" type="text" disabled="true">
            </div>
            <div class="form_line">
                <p class="text">Трудовой стаж на последнем <br> месте работы (в месяцах)</p>
                <input id="job_3" type="text" disabled="true">
            </div>
            <div class="form_line">
                <p class="text">Полный ежемесячный доход (в рублях)</p>
                <input id="job_4" type="text" disabled="true">
            </div>
            <div class="form_line">
                <p class="text">Должность</p>
                <input id="job_5" type="text" disabled="true">
            </div>
            <div class="form_line">
                <p class="text">Рабочий телефон</p>
                <input id="job_6" type="text" disabled="true">
            </div>
            <input type="button" name="next" class=" red" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ">
        </form>
```

вот тут код на JS

```
function job() {
var job = document.getElementById('job');
var job_arr = [];
job_arr.push(document.getElementById('job_1'));
job_arr.push(document.getElementById('job_2'));
job_arr.push(document.getElementById('job_3'));
job_arr.push(document.getElementById('job_4'));
job_arr.push(document.getElementById('job_5'));
job_arr.push(document.getElementById('job_6'));

    if(job.checked) {
        for (var i = 0; i < job_arr.length; i++) {
            job_arr[i].disabled = false;
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < job_arr.length; i++) {
            job_arr[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }
```

}

При этом, когда клацаешь по чекбоксу, ничего не меняется. Почему?

Answer (score 1):

Конфликт имен:

```
onclick="jobClick()"

function jobClick() {
```

В таких случаях полезно посмотреть ошибки в консоли браузера.

> job is not a function

Элемент с `name="job"` перекрывал определение функции `job`.

Не ограничивайте Ваш креатив в деле придумывания названий для элементов, функций и переменных.

Comment: Интересно, почему так работает, а в оригинале - нет?